# Calculate YTD, Previous YTD in the same query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How could I calculate to calculate YTD and prior YTD in the same query?

I try to calculate weight and weight ytd. I didn't undestand how to add the calculation of prior ytd in the same query.

- YTD: Sum Weight  from the first of January to today
- prior YTD: Sum
  Weight from the first of January of last year  to today minus 1 year

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
                   WHEN convert(date,s.Delivery_Year+'-'+ s.Delivery_month+'-'+ s.Delivery_day) BETWEEN dateadd(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE() THEN s.Weight
                   ELSE 0
               END) AS WeightYTD ,
           sum(Weight) AS weight ,
           [Sales_Organization] ,
           [Market_Grp] ,
           [Delivery_Year] ,
           [Delivery_month] ,
           Delivery_day
    FROM Fact_sales s
    GROUP BY ,
                      [Sales_Organization] ,
                      [Market_Grp] ,
                      [Delivery_Year] ,
                      [Delivery_month] ,
                      Delivery_day
```

Comment: You're selecting all data for all dates, and then grouping by year, month and date.  So, your output results will include rows for last year as well as this year.  What should rows from last year have in their year to date column?  *(For example, taking today's date, `20th March 2019`, you'll also have an output row for `21st March 2018`, should that row's year to date column show 2019's year to date values?)*

Comment: @MatBailie no  it should'nt

Comment: Then please edit your question, to update it with details that cover the full range of behaviours you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still quite unclear as to what results/behaviour you actually want.

One possible interpretation is that the "year to date" is relative to the date in the table, and not relative to "today" / `GETDATE()`.

So...

- for `14th March 2018` : YTD = `1st Jan 2018` to `14th March 2018`
- for `20th March 2019` : YTD = `1st Jan 2019` to `20th March 2019`

That being the case, I would do the following to get the `YTD` column...

```
WITH
    grouped_by_date AS
(
    SELECT
        [Sales_Organization],
        [Market_Grp],
        [Delivery_Year],
        [Delivery_Month],
        [Delivery_Day],
        SUM([Weight])             AS Weight
    FROM
        Fact_sales s
    GROUP BY
        [Sales_Organization],
        [Market_Grp],
        [Delivery_Year],
        [Delivery_Month],
        [Delivery_Day]
),
    cumulative_sum_for_ytd AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Delivery_Year]
                                ORDER BY [Delivery_Month], [Delivery_Day]
                           )
                              AS Weight_YTD
    FROM
        grouped_by_date
),
```

There isn't a `LAG()` function in SQL Server 2008, but there are "hacky tricks" that can simulate it...

```
    hack_to_do_lag AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE
            WHEN [Delivery_Year]%2=1
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN [Delivery_Year]%2=0 THEN [Weight_YTD] END) OVER (PARTITION BY ([Delivery_Year]+0)/2)
            ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN [Delivery_Year]%2=1 THEN [Weight_YTD] END) OVER (PARTITION BY ([Delivery_Year]+1)/2)
        END
            AS Weight_PreviousYTD
    FROM
        cumulative_sum_for_ytd
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    hack_to_do_lag
```

Comment: this part of code throws error  SUM([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Delivery_Year]
                                    ORDER BY [Delivery_Month], [Delivery_Day]-----this part
                               )
                                  AS Weight_YTD

Comment: @testtest 1). You changed the code, so your question doesn't reflect how you're testing it.  2). You didn't include the error message.  `Please update your question with the exact code you tested and the exact error message you received.`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: @testtest `Please update your question with the exact code you tested `

Comment: this part of your code throws error SUM([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Delivery_Year] ORDER BY [Delivery_Month], [Delivery_Day]-----this part ) AS Weight_YTD ----------- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26 Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: @testtest - Please update YOUR QUESTION (not a comment) with the EXACT (as in, full, complete, and not just one line) code that you tested.

Comment: I test exactly your script. It sems that I have a problem with compatibility

Comment: this my version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 12:32:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)